# How to enable users to bookmark the current location of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe on my page. The domain in the iframe is not mine/I don't control it but I want to make it as easy as possible for the user to bookmark the "current" location (not the SRC value) of the iframe .

With Same Origin Policy limitations considered, what would be the most user friendly way to do this?

For example is it possible (i doubt) to open the open the bookmark/favorites dialog, if not shouldn't there be? I don't think it violates same origin policy, does it?

Answer (score 1):

The Same Origin Policy prevents you from gathering information on the Iframe contents. Sorry.

Comment: I'm know that, hence this question.

Comment: OK, then the answer is: you can't.